# WinError 183 with os.rename()

Tags: python, file-rename

I'm running a `python3.3` script in win7.
At the end of the run I'm deleting a copyFile and renaming the tempFile as copyFile as so:

```
os.remove(scancpName)

os.rename(scantmpName, scancpName)
```

Although I'm removing the old copyFile before renaming I'm getting the call:

> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file
>   already exists

Am I missing something here?

Comment: just use `shutil.move`

Comment: Got no problems here running this

Comment: thanks. I used shutil.rmtree to remove the temp folder when run is done. But I would like to know how is it possible to get that call after the file was removed with os.remove.

Comment: But still somehow my PC thinks there is...

Comment: @jamylak, I think you can put your comment as a valid answer at least it helped me